# How to keep my Location Services running on every page of my Windows Phone mango application

Tags: c#, silverlight, windows-phone-7.1

in my windows phone mango application i am using location services. Now what i want is that what ever the page user navigates the location service keep sensing and keep updating about the current position using WCF call.
Currently it is working fine on 1 page. but when I navigate to another page it did't work. I know it is related to design of the application.

Please suggest the best course of action, if possible in detail.

Thanks

Comment: It would help to show some of your code -- where is you GeoCoordinateWatcher initialised, for example?

Comment: Rowland, I am instiating the GeoCoordinateWatcher in the page

Answer (score 0):

make a app level GeoCoordinateWatcher instance and initialise it once. keep using till you close / deactivate the app

Comment: Hermit, you mean I should put all my logic of GeoCorrdinateWatcher its events and everything in the app.xaml.cs file and even call WCF service from app.xaml.cs and it will continue its work regardless of the application page user is visiting.

Comment: No, that's what the Model/ViewModel is for

Comment: sorry dont tend to use MVVM - make small projects and MVVM makes them too complicated. Other than that yes i would do it just like that